# How to monitor Apache camel routes in a Java project using hawtio

Tags: java, apache-camel, monitoring, hawtio

Usually if we develop a java camel application using Java DSL then its very difficult to monitor the camel routs. To check whether the routes are running or not we need an extra monitoring application need to be developed.

But Hawtio ease our work in that. If your project is web application project then Hawtio has already camel component for it. So with out any extra efforts it will directy work.

But for Java Application it is not showing the routes.

Answer (score 2):

When we develop a java camel application we need some extra works to be done in order to view the routs.

**Steps for configuring java related camel application on hawtio**

1. Download the hawtio from https://hawt.io/getstarted/ 
   [image]
2. Place the war file in tomcat webapps folder --> start the tomcat web server.
   ( If you don’t have tomcat then please download the same from https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi )

Goto: http://localhost:8080/sample-1.5.6/welcome to view the hawtio
 [image]
Note:  At the first time there will be no Container tab.

3. To make use of hawtio in JVM (for java related application) we use Jolokia.
   Download Jolokia from https://jolokia.org/download.html

[image]

4. Command to attach Jolokia on the fly (No code changes required). We can use same jar file for deployment purposes.

Use the following command line argument:

```
    java <location of Jolokia agent.jar file> =host=0.0.0.0 -jar <location of our jar file>
```

Example:

```
    java -javaagent:jolokia-jvm-1.4.0-agent.jar=host=0.0.0.0 -jar C:\Users\HackoMan\Documents\GitHub\target\myjar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

[image]

5. Goto: http://localhost:8080/sample-1.5.6/welcome hawtio --> Connect --> Discovery --> press run/play button as mentioned below.
6. This opens a new tab. Press camel tab to view all of our route.

Then click on any route that either you want to debug or trace or to find details about it.
 [image]
 [image]

Comment: Can you update answer for spring boot and for new update in hawtio.

Comment: @ShibinRajuMathew Hi, sorry, cant help much in this case. I have not worked on spring boot(other than rest service creation)

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck doing this. After reading some documentation and blogs I could monitor Camel routes using Hawtio.

- Spring Boot 2.3.4.RELEASE
- Camel 3.4.3
- Hawtio 2.10.1

**Dependencies**

**For Spring Boot, it's not necessary if you already have conifgured the project.**

Auto-detects camel routes in Spring Context and register Camel utilities
(like producer template, consumer template and the type converter) as beans.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

To have support for auto-configuration from properties

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

**For manage routes using Jolokia as agent.**

To allow camel routes been manage by jolokia

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-management</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

To run jolokia and expose metrics over Http

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
        <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**Properties**

Expose Jolokia endpoint

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=jolokia
```

For not to use the word "*actuator*" as part of the endpoint when exposing jolokia

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
```

For configuring Jolokia endpoint path

```
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.jolokia=medidas
```

For setting custom port

```
server.port=8778
```

**Finally**

1. Start the project
2. Start Hawtio

   **java -jar hawtio-app-2.10.1.jar**
3. In web broser

   http://localhost:8080/hawtio
4. Configure the connection, test the connection.

   [Connection Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2XBI.png)

5. The last step is connect and automatically you will see camel routes

Answer (score 1):

Add follwoing dependency to spring boot app.

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>io.hawt</groupId>
      <artifactId>hawtio-springboot</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Add following properties for getting started without auth.

```
hawtio.authenticationEnabled = false
hawtio.offline = true
```

Complete example available over here:

https://github.com/jinternals/camel/

Comment: What is `hawtio.offline` for?